# give privilege to editor in wordpress to edit menu

Tags: wordpress

How to give privilege to editor in wordpress to edit,add or delete the menu items.Is it possible without using a plugin.Is there any way to do it by changing any functions in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the functions.php of your theme and assign the role of editor the ability to edit theme options.

```
$role = get_role( 'editor' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

Be aware that this way those with the editor role will also be able to edit the themes and widgets.